# How to convert file to uri content in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want record audio and after record this file show me path such as : **file://...** but I want show this such as **content://** . 
For this I write below codes but after run application show me this error. 
**Logcat error:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for
> provider with authority com.myapp.fileprovider
> at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:664)
> at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:695)
> at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:645)
> at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:449)

But I added this file into xml folder of res : 
**provider_path.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And added this code into Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And finally my code for convert file to uri content:

```
selectedFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file)
```

Show me error for above line! 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Your metadata does not match where `file` is located, apparently. What is `file`? Where is it pointing?

Comment: @CommonsWare create voice audio this this code : `private fun getRecordingFilePath(): String {
        val contextWrapper = ContextWrapper(requireContext())
        val voice = contextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
        val file = File(voice, "recordedVoice.mp3")
        return file.path
    }`